# Concatenating strings containing " and & characters

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

**Problem**

I am working with some Excel slicers through VBA, and need to filter (a varying number of) items at the same time.

The slicer commands include the """ and "&" characters, however, which obviously is problematic.

I've tried treating the """ and "&" characters individually, e.g. `"Some text" & """ & str1 & "&" & "more text"`, as well as trying to bundle it all together, e.g. `"Some text"" & str1 & "&more text"`

Neither approach seems to work, generating a "Compile error: Expected: End of statement".

---

**Question**

Is there a better way to include the "&" and """ characters in a concatenation?

---

**More Context**

This is the actual string layout I am trying to end up with, after all concatenation is complete:

```
"[Jobs].[ParentJob].&[Code1]", "[Jobs].[ParentJob].&[Code2]", "[Jobs].[ParentJob].&[Code3]"
```

Where *Jobs* and *ParentJob* remain the same (they are slicer categories and should be part of the string); but Code1, Code2 etc... are variables which are to be concatenated one by one as a loop runs.

I'm confident running the loop and concatenating the right parts in the right places, I just can't find any resources anywhere that explain how to include " and & in concatenations when they are in a more complex format.

Comment: To add the ampersand to a string you can use something like CHR(38): `"Some text" & """ & str1 & CHR(38) & "more`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single `"` I normally use `""""` (4 doble quotes).

It's annoying but it works pretty good. So for your test, if I do:

`Debug.Print """" & "[Jobs].[ParentJob].&[Code1]" & """" & ", " & """" & _
"[Jobs].[ParentJob].&[Code2]" & """" & ", " & """" & "[Jobs].[ParentJob].&[Code3]" & """"`

in the inmediate Window I get as output the text:

`"[Jobs].[ParentJob].&[Code1]", "[Jobs].[ParentJob].&[Code2]", "[Jobs].[ParentJob].&[Code3]"`

Hope this helps

**UPDATE**: For the char `&` there is no problem as long as it's between double quotes. Handle it as any other char text. So doing `"&"` will return `&` and doing `"[Jobs].[ParentJob].&[Code1]"`, will return `[Jobs].[ParentJob].&[Code1]`

**UPDATE 2:** Another option to make the code more readable would be assigning the `""""` to a string variable. Something like this:

```
Dim DblQuote As String

DblQuote = """"

Debug.Print DblQuote & "[Jobs].[ParentJob].&[Code1]" & DblQuote & ", " & DblQuote & _
"[Jobs].[ParentJob].&[Code2]" & DblQuote & ", " & DblQuote & "[Jobs].[ParentJob].&[Code3]" & DblQuote
```

This will output the text you need, but it's easier to work with it and make the code readable.

Comment: That's worked perfectly thanks - do you by any chance know why this works and/or why it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere? Or is it just one of those things? Seems kind of counterintuitive to my average at best coding experience...

Comment: To be honest, I did not find any official documentation. I saw this long time ago in a forum/website and because it worked, I use it. There are more ways to do it, but I'm afraid I can't give a documented answer. The only thing I found is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/criteria-expressions/include-quotation-marks-in-string-expressions but in my daily routine I work as suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have the option to use multiple quotes as [suggested by @foxfire](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57570147/6908282). But I would also recommend using the [**CHR function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/chr-function) in VBA.

In VBA you can use **Chr(38)** & **Chr(34)** for "&" and (double quote - ") respectively.
i.e:

**Chr(38)** = & 
and 
**Chr(34)** = "