# Replace customer ID with VBA variable in FindById() function?

Tags: excel, vba, string, variant, sap-gui

I am trying to automate some of my SAP work with VBA. I am stuck in the sign in as the script to customer price file is

```vb
session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlPRM_CC3000_1/shellcont/shell").SapEvent "Frame0", "sapbu_cl= &sapse_cl= &sapin_cl=S1F1E6~L&evtcode=ENTR&scroll_pos=0&S1F1E1L=2000&S1F1E2L=10&S1F1E3L=**98701**&S1F1E4L=&S1F1E4H=&S1F1E5L=&S1F1E5H=&S1F1E6L=12.10.2022", "sapevent:S1F1"
```

This is working well for the individual customer ID but I would like to loop through all the customers with different ID's specified in (Sheet 1, starting from A2). Therefore in this script I would need to use variable to replace the customer ID `98701`. I found an instruction of using `Cvar(Customer)`. However it leaves the Customer cell empty.

The code is below:

```vb
Dim i As Integer
Dim Customer As String

i = 2

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))

  Customer = Range("A" & i)

  On Error Resume Next

  ...
  session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlPRM_CC3000_1/shellcont/shell").SapEvent "Frame0", _
    "sapbu_cl= &sapse_cl= &sapin_cl=S1F1E6~L&evtcode=ENTR&scroll_pos=0&S1F1E1L=2000" _
    & "&S1F1E2L=10&S1F1E3L=Cvar(Customer)&S1F1E4L=&S1F1E4H=" _
    & "&S1F1E5L=&S1F1E5H=&S1F1E6L=12.10.2022", _
    "sapevent:S1F1" 
  ...

  i = i + 1
Loop
```

`Session.FindById(...)` seems to be string and I cannot include variant as a value to it.

The cell has a field name as well to write or point out directly.

[image: SAP field ID]

However I cannot find instructions on how to point to the certain field name directly in this case or include the variant to the `Session.FindById` string. Other solutions are welcome also!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `CStr` instead and concatenate the strings correctly

```
session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlPRM_CC3000_1/shellcont/shell").SapEvent "Frame0", _
    "sapbu_cl= &sapse_cl= &sapin_cl=S1F1E6~L&evtcode=ENTR&scroll_pos=0&S1F1E1L=2000" _
    & "&S1F1E2L=10&S1F1E3L=" & CStr(Customer) & " S1F1E4L=&S1F1E4H=" _
    & "&S1F1E5L=&S1F1E5H=&S1F1E6L=12.10.2022", _
    "sapevent:S1F1"
```

Maybe the following links shed light on the topic string concatenation

[How can I concatenate strings in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727699/how-can-i-concatenate-strings-in-vba)

[Concatenating strings containing " and & characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570006/concatenating-strings-containing-and-characters)